# Issues of using "THREE.BufferGeometry()" in the more recent three.js (r71): no mesh in the scene, glDrawArrays and vertexAttribPointer related errors

Tags: javascript, three.js, revision-history

I tried the example from the website: http://www.aptagraphis.com/3ds_samples/ship/, and it works fine. However, they use the 63th revison of three.js. When I use more recent the 71th revision of three.js, the mesh does not appear on the scene, and console outputs the errors like:

```
three_r71.js:20261 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: vertexAttribPointer: no bound ARRAY_BUFFER
5index.html:1 [.WebGLRenderingContext-05EBE9A0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
```

The simplified and extracted code which causes the issues:

```
function create_geometry (scene) {

      var material;
      var geometry;
         geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
         geometry.attributes = {
         position: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array([
            38.584, 3086.240, -1251.993,
            38.584, 2854.030, -665.175,
            -41.416, 2854.030, -665.175,
             38.584, 2251.488, -505.608
            ])
         },
         normal: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array([
            0.000, -0.930, -0.368,
            0.000, -0.930, -0.368,
            38.584, 1726.241, -311.993,
            1.000, 0.000, 0.000
            ])
         },
         uv: {
            itemSize: 2,
            array: new Float32Array([
               0.624, 0.344,
               0.085, 0.380,
               0.085, 0.656,
               0.624, 0.344
            ])
         }
         };
         material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
         var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
         scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Adding "geometry.computeTangents();" did not solve anything.

Which upgrades did cause that error? How to avoid it using three.js (r71)?